# jq rename nested json key and place under same key

Tags: jq

I want to rename nested json key and keep under same schema.

```
Input:

"properties":
 {
  "name": "Ram",
  "age": "17",
  "department": "Sony"
 }

Code : jq '[.["properties.company"] = .properties.department| del(.properties.department)]'  file
```

Output:

```
"properties":
 {
  "name": "Ram",
  "age": "17"  
 }
"properties.company" = "Sony"
```

Expected Output should be :

```
"properties":
 {
  "name": "Ram",
  "age": "17",
  "company": "Sony"  
 }
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options, but for that you need to have a valid input JSON such as:

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "name": "Ram",
    "age": "17",
    "department": "Sony"
  }
}
```

#### With `del`

This assigns the new property first, then deletes the old one.

```
.properties | .company = .department | del(.department)
```

#### Constructing a new object with `{}`

This is building a new object from scratch, copying all existing properties and renaming as needed.

```
.properties |= { name, age, company: .department }
```

#### Merging objects

This is a combination of the first two approaches. The property is deleted, while it is being renamed in the new object. Both objects are ultimately merged to form the result.

```
.properties |=  del(.department) + { company: .department }
```

#### Changing key name with `with_entries`

This iterates over all key-value pairs and (re-)assigns the key name.

```
.properties |= with_entries(.key |= if . == "department" then "company" else . end)
```

or if you dislike ifs: same as above, but uses `select(cond) // alternative` to select an alternative value unless the condition is met.

```
.properties |= with_entries(.key |= (select(. != "department") // "company"))
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I am new to jq can you please update above with full commands with jq included.

Comment: @Bokambo what do you mean with jq included? Those are all standalone jq programs, I cannot include any more jq.

Comment: @Bokambo you are missing the quotes since the program contains whitespace and reserved shell characters. To prevent the shell from consuming them, you must quote the program. But since that was already part of the initial question I thought this part was clear?